# Junit 5 + Mockito in Service Layer FetchById Method return null object retrieve from service

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

I tried to test the FetchById method in my BookServiceTest using Mockito but this error occurred
I'm using JUnit 5 and Mockito, that come along with spring boot starter test in spring boot version 3.1.3

the error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: not <null>

    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.build(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:152)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionFailureBuilder.buildAndThrow(AssertionFailureBuilder.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.failNull(AssertNotNull.java:49)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertNotNull.assertNotNull(AssertNotNull.java:30)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull(Assertions.java:301)
    at com.bookstore.com.serviceLevelTest.BookServTest.isFetchByIdValid(BookServTest.java:123)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

Here is my test class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BookServTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BookServTest.class);
    @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Mock
    private ModelMappers modelMapper;
    @Mock
    AuthorService authorService;


    private BookService bookService;


    //Mock Object

    List<Book> bookDtos;
    private Book book;


    private BookDto bookDto;
    private Author author;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
    bookService = new BookService(modelMapper,bookRepository,authorService);

        //Create BookDto
        bookDto = new BookDto();
        bookDto.setId(1L);
        bookDto.setTitle("The Usual Suspect");
        bookDto.setCategory("Crime");
        bookDto.setPrice(7800.55);
        bookDto.setAuthorName("Somxai");

        //Create Book
        book = new Book();
                book.setId(1L);
                book.setTitle("The Usual Suspect");
                book.setCategory("Crime");
                book.setPrice(7800.55);

        //Create list of bookDto
        bookDtos = new ArrayList<>();
        bookDtos.add(new Book(1L, "The Usual Suspect","Crime",7800.50));
        bookDtos.add(new Book(2L, "The Shutter Island","Crime",9000.50));
        bookDtos.add(new Book(3L, "The Shutter Island","Crime",9000.50));

        //Create Author
        author = new Author("Somxai","SSM","Laos PDR");

    }


//The error method:
 @Test
    void isFetchByIdValid(){
        //Arrange
        Mockito.when(bookRepository.fetchById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of(book)); //as i have checked this method is ok
        //Act
        BookDto bookDTO = bookService.fetchById(1L); // bookDTO return null
        //Assert
        Assertions.assertNotNull(bookDTO);

    }

//this method work fine
 @Test
    void isFetchAllValid(){
        //Arrange
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0,3,Sort.by("title").descending());
        Page<Book> expectedPage = new PageImpl<>(bookDtos, pageable, bookDtos.size());
        Mockito.when(bookRepository.findAll(pageable)).thenReturn(expectedPage);
        //Act
        List<BookDto> bookDtos1 = bookService.fetchAll(0,3,"title");
        //Assertion
        Assertions.assertNotNull(bookDtos1);
        Assertions.assertEquals(3,bookDtos1.size());
    }
```

Here is service method:

```
@Transactional
    @Cacheable(value = "book", key = "#id")
    public BookDto fetchById(Long id) {
        Optional<Book> book = bookRepository.fetchById(id);
        if (book.isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("book not found");
        }
        Book book1 = book.get();

        return modelMapper.bookToDTO(book1);
    }
```

Here is repository method:

```
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT b FROM Book b JOIN FETCH b.author a WHERE b.id = :id")
    Optional<Book> fetchById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Here is mapping method from model mapper:

```
public BookDto bookToDTO(Book book){

            BookDto bookDto = new BookDto();
            bookDto = modelMapper().map(book, BookDto.class);
            if (book.getAuthor() != null){
                bookDto.setAuthorName(book.getAuthor().getFirstName() + " " + book.getAuthor().getLastName());
            }
            return bookDto;
        }
```

I have been searching for a similar issue and tried many approaches but not work for me.
note: When I tested in Postman, every method working fine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much! The issue is in the mapping Process
Here is the code that passed.

```
@Test
void isFetchByIdValid(){
        Book bookSetup = new Book(1L,"Onepiece","Advanture",500.50);

        Optional<Book> optionalBook = Optional.of(bookSetup);

      // Arrange
        Mockito.when(bookRepository.fetchById(1L)).thenReturn(optionalBook);

        BookDto bookDto = new BookDto();
        bookDto.setId(bookSetup.getId());
        bookDto.setTitle(bookSetup.getTitle());
        bookDto.setCategory(bookSetup.getCategory());
        bookDto.setPrice(bookSetup.getPrice());

        Mockito.when(modelMapper.bookToDTO(bookSetup)).thenReturn(bookDto);
        // Act
        BookDto bookDTO = bookService.fetchById(1L);

        // Debugging
        System.out.println("book: " + bookSetup);
        System.out.println("bookDTO from service Test : " + bookDTO);
        System.out.println("BooDto from mapping: " + bookDto);

        // Assert
        Assertions.assertNotNull(bookDTO);
```

Comment: this answer is correct this code is fixed